# Preventing air conditioner from running when temp is below 65 degrees outside

Tags: air-conditioning, air

Could l wire a thermostat outside and and set is to 68 degrees and use it as a switch to prevent the air conditioner condenser from running when below 68 degrees. And use in-line with the yellow wire.

Comment: I'm sure you _could_... Is there a problem with the indoor stat that's causing the AC to run even though the house is cool enough inside? Seems like solving _that_ problem would make more sense.

Comment: @FreeMan I think the OP is part way to "if the *outside* temperature gets low, I want to turn off the A/C  **and** automatically open windows instead.  I agree it's silly.

Comment: Patrick,  it's trivial to wire two thermostats in parallel, thus requiring both of them to read their local temperature as greater than your setpoint.  However, as the comments point out, it's the wrong solution to your problem

Comment: There are plenty of home automation setups, @CarlWitthoft, that would _very easily_ handle this. Of course it requires a computer (like a RaspberryPi for less than the cost of a new stat), and some other bits of hardware and free software. But it could, actually, turn off the AC and open a window (or two).

Comment: Don't forget to factor in relative humidity. Just because outside temp may be below 65, if humidity is 95% I don't want to open my windows and may still need some AC to keep house comfortable.

Comment: @carl witthoft  thermostats in parallel create an or circuit if either A or B stat is on the system turns on.

Comment: Patrick most mechanical thermostats are single pole single throw. Verify the thermostat you want to put in line opens below 68 (opens below the set point). This will do exactly what you want when in-line on the call for cool.

Comment: @EdBeal  you are right -- apologies for miswriting.

Comment: But why would you want to do this? If the outside temp is 65 F and the thermostat calls for cooling, and the inside thermostat is set to say 72 F, then heat generation inside the house could legitimately call for cooling and you would want the condensing unit to turn on. At 65 F ambient wouldn't the power consumption of the condensing unit be relatively low? I suppose someone might want this if residents were disregarding instructions to turn off the a/c entirely and open windows at 65 F ambient.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how good of an idea this is, what you want is possible and is actually common for heat pump systems (albeit at freezing temperatures).  Your outdoor unit just has a pair of wires going to it that allow the indoor thermostat to switch it on.  You would just need to find an outdoor thermostat that has the range you want and wire it in to the control wire.  Its low voltage, so it's a simple and safe DIY project as long as you disconnect the power to the outside unit before opening the panel.

One issue is that the indoor thermostat would still turn on the blower inside, but it would just circulate air in the house and not cool.  The blower could come on for a long time if circulating the air doesn't cool the area the thermostat is in.